# Drupal - Custom form submit

Tags: php, html, drupal

I know 0 about drupal and unfortunately don't have much control over modules and things like that.

That said...  I need to make a form submit an email to a recipient, it's a pretty standard form, with a file attach.  I have a script that was pre-written for me and is confirmed working on a separate PHP site.  I'm running into some issues using it on drupal however.  Basically I get a 405 Not Allowed error on submit of the form...  We have a tracking software that normally handles our form submissions, unfortunately it can not handle file attachments, and so I have to use a custom PHP script in order to send the email.  The script is made in such a way to pair with our tracking software so that we can still track form submissions.

The page the code is on is set as PHP code for type. (as opposed to full html, or filtered html).  The file on the server is temporarily chmod 777 - though I should only need 666 right?

Why am I getting this 405 Not Allowed error?

Here's some code:

HTML for the form:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="/sites/www.mathistire.com/files/mailfile-job.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>

    <tr>
        <td><label title="Name">Name:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label title="E-Mail">E-Mail:</label></td><td><input type="email" name="EMail" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label title="Position">Position:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="Position" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label title="Attach">Attach File:</label></td><td><input type="file" name="import_file" alt="import_file" title="import_file" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

PHP mailfile:

```
<?php
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','24M');
ini_set('post_max_size','32M');

if ($_POST) {
    $field_tracking = "";
    $now = date("D m/d/Y H:i:s e");

    // case normalized list of field names that we don't want to encapsulate in xml
    $metafieldnames = array("submit","imemailsubject","imredirect","formname","imdefaultrecipient","import_file","max_file_size","x","y");

    // build the email message from the list of fields list 
    $emailxtra="INFORMATION FROM WEB FORM: ".$_POST['formname'].": " . $now . "\n\n";
    //check for post values
    while(list($key, $value) = each($_POST)) {      
        if(is_array($value)){ 
            $value = implode(', ',$value);
        }

        //add value to scope
        $$key = $value;

        // only encapsulate fields that are not metadata fields or submit button
        if (!in_array (strtolower($key), $metafieldnames) ) {
            $emailxtra=$emailxtra.$key.": ".stripslashes($value)."\r\n\r\n";
            $field_tracking .= "\nurl += '&".$key."=' + escape('".addslashes($value)."');";
        }       
    }   
    //echo ('FIELD TRACKING: ' . $field_tracking);


    //create the email
    $mime_boundary = "<<<--==+X[".md5(time())."]"; 

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: ".$imEmailField."\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$EMail."\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n"; 
    $headers .= " boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\""; 

    $mail_message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n"; 
    $mail_message .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n"; 
    $mail_message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"; 
    $mail_message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"; 
    $mail_message .= $emailxtra."\r\n";


    $upload_error = "";
    if ($_FILES && count($_FILES) > 0) {
        //upload file 1
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['import_file']['tmp_name'])) {
            if(preg_match("/.exe$|.com$|.bat$|.rar$|.egs$/i", $_FILES['import_file']['name'])){
              $upload_error = "Attempted to upload .exe .com .rar .egs or .bat file.";
            }
        //echo ('file uploaded');
        } 

        else {
        switch($_FILES['import_file']['error']){
            case 0: //no error; possible file attack!
                $upload_error = "no error; possible file attack!";
                break;
            case 1: //uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini
                $upload_error = "uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.";
                break;
            case 2: //uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the html form
                $upload_error = "uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the html form.";
                break;
            case 3: //uploaded file was only partially uploaded
                $upload_error = "uploaded file was only partially uploaded.";
                break;
            case 4: //no file was uploaded
                $upload_error = "No file was uploaded.";
                break;
            default: //a default error, just in case!  :)
                $upload_error = "There was a problem with your upload.";
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($upload_error != "") {
            $mail_message .= "ERROR with attachment 1 file ".$_FILES['import_file']['name'].":  ".$upload_error."\r\n";
        }
        else {
            $mail_message .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n"; 
            $mail_message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\r\n"; 
            $mail_message .= " name=\"".$_FILES['import_file']['name']."\"\r\n"; 
            $mail_message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 
            $mail_message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n"; 
            $mail_message .= " filename=\"".$_FILES['import_file']['name']."\"\r\n"; 
            $mail_message .= "\r\n"; 
            $fp = fopen($_FILES['import_file']['tmp_name'],"r");
            $contents = fread ($fp, filesize($_FILES['import_file']['tmp_name']));
            fclose($fp);
            $contents = chunk_split(base64_encode($contents));
            //echo $contents;
            //$mail_message .= strip_tags($contents); 
            $mail_message .= $contents; 
            //$mail_messagee .= "\r\n"; 
            //$mail_message .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n"; 
        }
    } //close check for files


    $recipient = "mhostiuckproductions@gmail.com";
    //echo $mail_message;
    mail($recipient,$subj_slug,$mail_message,$headers);

}  //close post check

//Insite    
$url = "http://www.insitemetrics.com/imv2/uRMJ/uniformv2.php?actk=6vdsc0-5yfrjtbfcq" . 
"&Name=" . $_REQUEST['Name'] .
"&EmailField=" . $_REQUEST['EMail'] .
"&Position=" . $_REQUEST['Position'] .
"&FileAttach=" . $_FILES['import_file']['name'];



header("location:".$url);
exit;   
//echo ("mail sent.");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Form Api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) and a custom module would probably be the way to go if you're going to use the existing code. But if you can install some modules [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) and a few other modules should produce this functionality with configuration and little to no code.

The way you are going about this functionality is not how drupal expects forms to be created so you will probably continue to run into issues with this pattern. [More info on drupal forms](http://drupal.org/node/1043838)

P.S. You should include your drupal version.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write form directly in drupal.

You need to create a custom module in drupal.
Drupal 7: http://drupal.org/node/1074360
Drupal 6: http://drupal.org/node/206753

Once you know how to write a basic module then you need to understand the procedure to add custom form in drupal or you can directly jump to this to use sample code provided here but you might not understand what is going on ;) :

Drupal 7: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syqsH2CEu6U / http://drupal.org/node/1043838
Drupal 6: http://drupal.org/node/751826

[Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) suggested by Alex might work for you but i am not sure if it provides file attachment facility which is part of your requirement.